# bootstrap iframe not resizing

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

The following code is working well except for the the size of the YouTube player. I cannot resize it to the size I want.

I tried to put `width="150"` and `height="100"` in iframe but nothing happened.

```js
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/q6xWV-uDl5E?autoplay=1" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me? Here is the jsfiddle to prove that. I also believe you might be missing `px` thats why it's not working for you.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekuwzbfd/)

and here is the code:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
   <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  
   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/q6xWV-uDl5E?autoplay=1" width=150px 
   height=100px allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

px doesn't matter if u write only as width="150" height="100",it works good,if you do not pass px than by default it gets to pixels.
the size u wants is not getting beacause in class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" so it is using 16by9,it is the aspect ratio which are used by it you can also pass other ratios such as 1by1 , 21by9, 4by3,etc

here for youTube video: width="560" height="315", the ratio is 16:9
width="640" height="498", the ratio is 4:3
for different ratios height and width are different,you can adjust it by setting different width and height as per ratios

Comment: yeahh i tried these but yet i cant find the size that i want! any solution to put my own height and width?

Answer (score 0):

if u want the size as per your width and height than remove class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" and add width and height you wan inside your iframe tag
like [[ src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4aQwT3n2c1Q" height="315" width="560" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"]]
and close the iframe tag,works fine.

Comment: i tried this ok it is working but now i lost the reposive.. what i want is the video to be responsive and mine height and width! thank you veru much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

{div class="responsive-embed"}
  {iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mM5_T-F1Yn4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen }{/iframe}
{div}
try this and u get your answe use open angular bracket instead of curly

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
       <div class="container">
           <iframe src="there is path of your iframe"></iframe> 
       </div>
   </div>


   .wrapper {
    width: 50%;
   }
.container {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.container iframe {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```